# Как убрать причину discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@client.command (pass_context = True)
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members = True)
async def ban (ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason):
    await ctx.channel.purge (limit =1) #тут есть ошибка. Если что поменяй 1 на бесконечность
    lol = discord.Embed(title = 'Пользователь забанен!', color = 0x9400D3 )
    lol.add_field(name = 'Модератор / админ:', value = ctx.message.author.mention, inline = False)
    lol.add_field(name = 'Нарушитель:', value = member.mention, inline = False)
    lol.add_field(name= 'Причина:', value = reason, inline = False)
    lol.set_thumbnail(url = 'https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2020/11/27/74c6f0135d52e0f6f02f649184dcfef4-full.jpg')
    lol.set_footer (text = f'Вызвано: {ctx.message.author}', icon_url = ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(embed = lol)
    await member.send(f'Вы забанены по причине "{reason}"!')
    await member.ban( reason = reason)
```

Как можно сделать так, чтобы причину можно было не писать, но если пользователь написал причину, то эта причина будет выводиться в embed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно указать стандартное значение, которое будет использоваться в случае отсутствия аргумента:

```
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason: str = 'Стандартная причина'):
```

Answer (score 1):

Замените строку:

```
async def ban (ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason):
```

на:

```
async def ban (ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason = "None"):
```

Параметрам функции можно заранее задавать значение.

Answer (score 0):

```
async def ban (ctx, member: Discord.Member,Reason=None)
```